# Java: Loop increment not starting at 0

Tags: java, for-loop, drawing, increment, zero

I've checked out other resources and haven't been able to find something helpful. But I'm attempting to figure out how to start loop increment at 0 instead of 1 for drawing the number inside the oval as shown below.

I'd appreciate the help.

My code: (Drawing Panel: http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java)

```
// Draws boxed ovals using a for loop.

import java.awt.*;

public class DrawLoopFor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(501, 251);
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        int sizeX = 50;
        int sizeY = 25;

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) 
        {
            int cornerX = i*50;
            int cornerY = i*25;

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(cornerX + 5, cornerY + 5, sizeX-10, sizeY-10);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("" + i, cornerX - 28, cornerY - 8);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(cornerX, cornerY, sizeX, sizeY);
        }
    }
}
```

My output (wrong):
[image: My incorrect output]

Correct output:
[image: Correct output]

Comment: What is `DrawingPanel` ? You're not importing it (and no such class exists in the Java standard API)

Comment: Your accumulator is starting at 0. There's another bug going on  here. Notice how the last element is without a label.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you're drawing the text inside the wrong box. In the call to `drawString`, change the `-`s to `+`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're drawing the text in the previous box rather than the current box. That's why the last box is empty, and the zero is drawn outside the visible screen.

Most likely because you subtract 28 from cornerX when you draw.

Try adding rather than subtracting.
As I don't have your `DrawingPanel` class I can't confirm the exact offsets to cornerX and cornerY that you need, but I think you should use something like:

```
g.drawString("" + i, cornerX + 22, cornerY + 17);
```

(22 for the X coordinate, since you were drawing the start of the text 3 pixels before the middle of the box, and 25 - 3 = 22; 17 for the Y coordinate because the height is 25, and you were previously drawing the baseline of the text 8 higher than the end of the box, so 25 - 8 = 17)

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 30 seconds :/

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry.. ;-) I think I have the coordinates right now to draw the text at the same place inside the box as previously.

Comment: It should work. Assuming it's using the standard window coordinate system (which is should be using), it should increase going to the bottom-right, so adding makes much more sense than subtracting.

Answer (score 1):

add `tempi` variable and put condition `if i=0` then temp=1 and multiply `tempi` instead of `i`

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) { 
    int tempi; 
    if(i==0) { 
        tempi=1; 
    } else { 
        tempi=i 
    } 
   int cornerX = tempi*50; int cornerY = tempi*25; 
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Won't this cause  2 ovals to overlay when i==1?